# How to create nested object schema with mongoose in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am creating collections schema in which i should also include *customFields* array of object which is defined below. But the schema i tried with , creating new Object Id for each property of customFields object. I need help to include customField object inside my collection schema

**Object from FRONT_END**

```json
{
    "name": "Ali",
    "topic": "Books",
    "description": "Gonnabe nice collection",
    "owner": "63397103eb71457cdff0c244",
    "customFields": [
        {
            "title": "Title",
            "type": ""
        },
        {
            "title": "Description",
            "type": "textarea"
        }
        {
            "title": "Number",
            "type": "number"
        }
    ]
}
```

**COLLECTION POST ROUTE**

```js
collectionRoute.post(
  "/",
  JWTAuthMiddleware,
  adminAndUserOnly,
  async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
      const collection = new CollectionModal(req.body);
      console.log(collection);
      await collection.save();
      const newCollection = await UsersModal.findByIdAndUpdate(
        req.body.owner,
        {
          $push: { collections: { ...collection, owner: req.user._id } },
        },
        { new: true }
      );
      res.status(201).send(newCollection);
    } catch (error) {
      next(error);
    }
  }
);
```

**Schema**

```js
import mongoose from "mongoose";
const { Schema, model } = mongoose;

const collectionSchema = new Schema(
  {
    name: { type: String },
    description: { type: String },
    topic: { type: String },
    image: { type: String },
    customFields: [
      {
        fieldNumber: { type: Number },
        fieldMultilineText: { type: String },
        fieldType: { type: String },
        fieldChecked: { type: Boolean },
        fieldDate: { type: Date },
      },
    ],
    owner: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" },
    items: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, require: true, ref: "Item" }],
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

collectionSchema.index({ "$**": "text" });
export default model("Collection", collectionSchema);
```

**USER SCHEMA**

```
const userSchema = new Schema(
  {
    username: { type: String },
    email: { type: String, unique: true },
    password: { type: String },
    role: { type: String, enum: ["user", "admin"], default: "user" },
    status: { type: String, enum: ["active", "blocked"], default: "active" },
    collections: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Collection" }],
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);
```

**Result**

[Here is req.body in my server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chpXJ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify `customFields` property to be of type `Object`, so it will accept whatever object you send.

```js
customFields: [{ type: Object }]
```

Comment: i think main problem is in my ciollection schema defining customField object. Because from client i am only sending title and type properties but in server i have multiple property of an object because type can be different every time. thats main reason i stuck in this point to include customField object

Comment: But you are trying to update the User. You probably created `collections` field as a reference to the `Collections` in the user schema. That is why only the `_ids` are saved. Can you include your user schema in the question as well?

Comment: updated. yes you are right. Because i am doin that when i get user with their collection. How can i save my customField object  with its full properties to collection schema?

Comment: Do you want to store them in user document, or you would like to keep it in the separate collection? How many collections each users will have? Can it be potentially unlimited?

Comment: yes i would like to keep them inside collection . But when i get user,  colections with its properties and customfields should come with specific user

Comment: Then you just have to use `populate()` method when getting the user. So you should do this `await Users.find(user_id).populate('collections')`.

Comment: it is working fine. The problem is saving customfield object coming from client to collection schema. U know i was sending only title and type of customField object but on the collections schema inside customField object i have multiple properties because type can be number, string, date and so on. So that is i was wondering how can i define customField object inside collection schema accprding to object coming from client.

Comment: You can specify it as type `Object`, so it will accept whatever you send.  `customFields: [{ type: Object }]`

Comment: All i was asking is this xD . thank you brother

Comment: You are welcome. I updated my answer in case someone will have the same issue as you. Consider also upvoting and accepting my answer so others would see that it worked for you.

Comment: Just in case can i update my custom field properties with this way as well as with other properties of collection?

Comment: Yes you can. You would just have to use the array operators to update array elements, and you would need unique identifier for each item.  If `title` property is always unique in the array, you should use that one. If not, you should let Mongoose create unique `_id` for each item of the array (which is enabled by default), and use that as identifier.